# What is the correct source code directory location in the "az bot publish" command for .net based bot

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

If I am [publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-basic-deploy?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#deploy-your-bot) the bot source code using **az bot publish** command, what is the correct path to **code-dir** parameter? It simply says path to the source code.

Following is project folder structure:

> c:\source\bot-solution\{Solution file }
>
> c:\source\bot-solution\{project-folder}\{project-file}

Is it the folder that contain my .net solution or is it the folder that contain my project file? Typically .net solution file is at the same level at the project folder and project folder contain the project file.

So is it going to be **c:\source\bot-solution** or **c:\source\bot-solution\{project-folder}**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the project folder (the one that contains your project file), not the solution folder.

```
c:\source\bot-solution\{project-folder}
```